# Inherited Equivalence in SubClass, how to get the same result with baseClass?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write an Equivalence function for my baseClass and subClasses. By "Equivalence" I mean that I want to check that all (or some) of the attributes of the compared instances are equal/equivalent.

My problem comes when I have a List of the base class and I want to check which elements have an equivalent match in the list.

Let's say the base class is called "Item". And the subclasses are "WeaponItem", "ConsumableItem", "EquipableItem", "ArmorItem", etc.. (Any number of subclasses with any number of depth of inheritance).

if I have an item list, I can only check the equivalence at the Item class level even though the instances could be of any of the subclasses.

My problem is that the equivalence at the base level gives me a different result than the equivalence a specific level:

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
WeaponItem weaponItem1 = new WeaponItem();
weaponItem1.strength = 1;
WeaponItem weaponItem2 = new WeaponItem();
weaponItem2.strength = 5;
WeaponItem weaponItem3 = new WeaponItem();
weaponItem3.strength = 5;
weaponItem1.IsEquivalent(weaponItem2);//returns false
weaponItem2.IsEquivalent(weaponItem3);//returns true
itemList.Add(weaponItem1);
itemList.Add(weaponItem2);
itemList[0].IsEquivalent(itemList[1]);//returns true

(itemList[0] as WeaponItem).IsEquivalent((WeaponItem)itemList[1]);//returns false
```

The IsEquivalent function in Item only checks one thing.
While the IsEquivalent function in WeaponItem checks all the attributes in the WeaponItem class.

So my question is how can I call the correct IsEquivalent function for any of the items in the List when I cannot cast the actual type because it could be any subclass of Item?

So in the example code above I would like to change the before-last line in a way that it returns false or change how I implement the IsEquivalent function.

Thank you for taking the time to look into this.

EDIT: So the error was with how I implemented the IsEquivalence methods I wasn't overriding the base function... I guess I was tired.
I'm assuming that if I was using IEquatable (Equals, ==, !=, GetHash) I would need it once for IEquatable<'Item> and then I would override these function for each subclass. There would be no need to add IEquatable<'WeaponItem> as well or am I wrong to think that?

Comment: Include your `IsEquivalent` **implementations** in the question please.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** by including a [mcve]. See also [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask). Also please take the [tour] (you get a badge!)

Comment: As it stands now I am going to vote your question to be closed due to no response on the request for including the `IsEquivalent` implementations. We should not have to guess as to how you write/implemented these methods and ig you are using proper inheritance techniques in c# you should not be having an issue. I can retract my vote once the question has been updated.

Comment: You have discovered a fundamental problem: it is difficult to construct correct equivalence relations in many OO languages because OO languages tend to be single dispatch predicates, but the equivalence relation is logically a doubly dispatched predicate. There are a variety of ways to try to tame this beast, but many of them just trade one set of problems for another. In my series https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/ I discuss how to implement other predicates in this domain, but most everything I say in this series applies to equivalence relations also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about is using on of the fundamental features of object-oriented programming: [polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).

Using polymorphism, calling `IsEquivalent` on an object calls the version implemented in the that object's actual class, and not the one in base class it is being referenced by.

So, here is an implementation:

```
public abstract class Item {
    public virtual bool IsEquivalent(Item i2) {
        return true;
    }
}

public class WeaponItem : Item {
    public int strength;

    public override bool IsEquivalent(Item i2) {
        var ans = base.IsEquivalent(i2);
        if (i2 is WeaponItem w2)
            ans = ans && strength == w2.strength;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

NOTE: If your equivalence can be more complex than just the two cases of `Item` vs `Item` when the two actual types are different, or SameType vs SameType (e.g. `WeaponItem` vs `WeaponItem`) when they are the same, you will need to use double-dispatch polymorphism to capture the first type and then delegate equivalency testing to the second `Item` to avoid type testing in each `IsEquivalent`. You could also use `dynamic` for double-dispatch if you don't mind the performance hit.